# React Leaflet Polygons not updating with properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to draw a set of polygons on a map and then change the color according to an external event which updates a property of the MapContainer. In my example the property is "view". I can see that the property value is updated properly but the polygons are not re-rendered. It's a simple set of polygon without Tile (no geographical map, only the polygons).
I tried both with color and fillColor, but nothing changes when I update "view". Should I somehow force a map refresh? If yes, how?

```
<MapContainer
        id="leaflet-map"        
        center={center}
        zoom={zoom}
      >
        {this.props.data.map((poly, index) => {          
          return (
            <Polygon
              key={`poly-${poly.id}`}
              color={poly.color[this.props.view]}
              fillColor={
                poly.color[this.props.view]
              }
              positions={poly.attributes.coordinates}              
            >              
            </Polygon>
          );
        })}
      </MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer. I hope this can help others.
I have to modify pathOptions.color and pathOptions.fillColor and not directly color and fillColor.
It works like this for me:

```
 <Polygon
              key={`poly-${poly.id}`}
              pathOptions={{  
                color: poly.color[this.props.view],
                fillColor: poly.color[this.props.view]
              }}
              positions={poly.attributes.coordinates}              
            >              
            </Polygon>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer! You saved my day! Yay!